# Command to find file names from grep of "string" inside files in Google cloud storage Buckets?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have many files in the GCS bucket and I would like to find the file name which contains my data (for ex: grep "APPLE"). Is there any way to find the file names based on the grep command?

The following command only results in the data with respective rows, but I want to find the file name in which the grep data resides

```
gsutil cat gs://my-bucket/part-2020-01-09** | grep 'APPLE'
```

Is there any way to find the respective file names?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to use the `-h` command line option

```
gsutil cat -h gs://my-bucket/part-2020-01-09** | grep 'APPLE'
```

This would print a header with the object name before the contents of each text object that matched the wildcard.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cat

Answer (score 2):

For doing this, I would write a script like this:

```
for i in $(gsutil ls gs://my-bucket/part-2020-01-09**) 
do 
    gsutil cat ${i} | grep 'APPLE' > /dev/null
    if [ "${?}" == "0" ] 
    then 
        echo ${i}
    fi
done
```

But it's not as efficient as a cat because it performs an API call for each file. I don't know the number of files that you have and if it's an acceptable solution.

Comment: Thank you @guillaume blaquiere

Comment: Yes as you said, its running very slowly